# A triangle ABC with the internal bisector of $\angle A$, the median drawn from B and the altitude drawn from C meet at the same point.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]

A triangle $ABC$ with the internal bisector of $\angle A$, the median drawn from $B$ and the altitude drawn from $C$ meet at the same point. Prove that $$\tan A = \dfrac{\sin C}{\cos B}$$

I try to solve it but I can't prove that $AB\cdot AE=AC\cdot BE$

Comment: you mean by converge that they meet at the same point right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've reduced to problem to showing that $AB\cdot AE = AC\cdot BE$, then you've presumably reduced all the trig, but have not used the concurrency of the lines in your solution?

The final result can be obtained by Ceva's theorem:
Given a triangle $ABC$ and concurrent lines $AF, BD, CE$, it states that $\frac{AD}{DC}\frac{CF}{FB}\frac{BE}{EA} = 1$.